# can i update my working war file in google application engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have developed an project in java and exported as war file it runs in tomcat . can i use this application in google application engine.

```
1) Will my war file works in google app engine.
2) Do i need to change any thing to make it work??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless we are talking about a "Hello World" type of application, you will most likely have to change some things to make it work.

In particular your interactions with a database will need to be re-thought to work with the app engine data store. Same goes for file system access (not possible on app engine) and a couple of sandboxed libraries.